# google link for the RGBA library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want google link for the RGBA library

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'></script>
```

This file contains

/*
 * jQuery Color Animations
 */

(function(jQuery){

```
// We override the animation for all of these color styles
jQuery.each(['backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'], function(i,attr){
    jQuery.fx.step[attr] = function(fx){
        if ( fx.colorFunction == undefined || fx.state == 0 ) {
            fx.start = getColor( fx.elem, attr );
            fx.end = getRGB( fx.end );

            if ( fx.start == undefined ) {
                fx.start = [ 255,255,255,0 ];
            } else { 
                if ( fx.start[3] == undefined ) // if alpha channel is not spotted
                    fx.start[3] = 1;            // assume it is fully opaque
                if ( fx.start[3] == 0 )         // if alpha is present and fully transparent
                    fx.start[0] = fx.start[1] = fx.start[2] = 255;  // assume starting with white
            }

            if ( fx.end[3] == undefined )   // if alpha channel is not spotted
                fx.end[3] = 1;              // assume it is fully opaque

            fx.colorFunction = ( fx.start[3] == 1 && fx.end[3] == 1 ? calcRGB : calcRGBa ); 
        }

        fx.elem.style[attr] = fx.colorFunction();
    }
});

var calcRGB = function() {
        return 'rgb(' + 
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[0] - this.start[0])) + this.start[0]), 255), 0) + ',' +
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[1] - this.start[1])) + this.start[1]), 255), 0) + ',' + 
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[2] - this.start[2])) + this.start[2]), 255), 0) + ')';
    };
var calcRGBa = function() {
        return 'rgba(' + 
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[0] - this.start[0])) + this.start[0]), 255), 0) + ',' +
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[1] - this.start[1])) + this.start[1]), 255), 0) + ',' + 
            Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((this.pos * (this.end[2] - this.start[2])) + this.start[2]), 255), 0) + ',' +
            Math.max(Math.min( parseFloat((this.pos * (this.end[3] - this.start[3])) + this.start[3]), 1), 0) + ')';
    };

// Color Conversion functions from highlightFade
// By Blair Mitchelmore
// http://jquery.offput.ca/highlightFade/

// Parse strings looking for color tuples [255,255,255]
function getRGB(color) {
    var result;

    // Check if we're already dealing with an array of colors
    if ( color && color.constructor == Array && color.length >= 3 )
        return color;

    // Look for rgb(num,num,num)
    if (result = /rgba?\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,?\s*((?:[0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?)?)\s*\)/.exec(color))
        return [ parseInt(result[1]), parseInt(result[2]), parseInt(result[3]), parseFloat(result[4]||1) ];

    // Look for rgb(num%,num%,num%)
    if (result = /rgba?\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,?\s*((?:[0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?)?)\s*\)/.exec(color))
        return [parseFloat(result[1])*2.55, parseFloat(result[2])*2.55, parseFloat(result[3])*2.55, parseFloat(result[4]||1)];

    // Look for #a0b1c2
    if (result = /#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(color))
        return [parseInt(result[1],16), parseInt(result[2],16), parseInt(result[3],16)];

    // Look for #fff
    if (result = /#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(color))
        return [parseInt(result[1]+result[1],16), parseInt(result[2]+result[2],16), parseInt(result[3]+result[3],16)];

    // Otherwise, we're most likely dealing with a named color
    var colorName = jQuery.trim(color).toLowerCase();
    if ( colors[colorName] != undefined )
        return colors[colorName];

    return [ 255, 255, 255, 0 ];
}

function getColor(elem, attr) {
    var color;

    do {
        color = jQuery.curCSS(elem, attr);

        // Keep going until we find an element that has color, or we hit the body
        if ( color != '' && color != 'transparent' || jQuery.nodeName(elem, "body") )
            break; 

        attr = "backgroundColor";
    } while ( elem = elem.parentNode );

    return getRGB(color);
};

// Some named colors to work with
// From Interface by Stefan Petre
// http://interface.eyecon.ro/

var colors = {
    aqua:[0,255,255],
    azure:[240,255,255],
    beige:[245,245,220],
    black:[0,0,0],
    blue:[0,0,255],
    brown:[165,42,42],
    cyan:[0,255,255],
    darkblue:[0,0,139],
    darkcyan:[0,139,139],
    darkgrey:[169,169,169],
    darkgreen:[0,100,0],
    darkkhaki:[189,183,107],
    darkmagenta:[139,0,139],
    darkolivegreen:[85,107,47],
    darkorange:[255,140,0],
    darkorchid:[153,50,204],
    darkred:[139,0,0],
    darksalmon:[233,150,122],
    darkviolet:[148,0,211],
    fuchsia:[255,0,255],
    gold:[255,215,0],
    green:[0,128,0],
    indigo:[75,0,130],
    khaki:[240,230,140],
    lightblue:[173,216,230],
    lightcyan:[224,255,255],
    lightgreen:[144,238,144],
    lightgrey:[211,211,211],
    lightpink:[255,182,193],
    lightyellow:[255,255,224],
    lime:[0,255,0],
    magenta:[255,0,255],
    maroon:[128,0,0],
    navy:[0,0,128],
    olive:[128,128,0],
    orange:[255,165,0],
    pink:[255,192,203],
    purple:[128,0,128],
    violet:[128,0,128],
    red:[255,0,0],
    silver:[192,192,192],
    white:[255,255,255],
    yellow:[255,255,0]
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Well, I guess you can Google :)

Comment: i have edited my post can you please check it now

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a link to the version of the plugin hosted by Google's CDN, then sorry, Google doesn't host any jQuery plugins, except for one - jQuery UI. A list of available libraries is available here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=RBGA+support+for+jQuery+Color#hl=en&sa=X&ei=-U8pTZDpLIXGvQPSoYHgBA&ved=0CBcQvgUoAA&q=RBGA+support+for+jQuery+Color&nfpr=1&fp=fc6a20d2a69824a5

Comment: Did you mean: RGBA support for jQuery Color. LOL

Comment: If you're referring to Google's hosted jquery (http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) then AFAIK they host the standard jquery distribution and that's it.